# Uninstalling Windows Mobile application doesn't remove file in IsolatedStorageFile

Tags: .net, windows-phone, isolatedstoragefile, windows-10-mobile

i have windows phone 8 application. i installed this application in a device running windows 10 mobile. after uninstalling application from device i found that the my sqlite db file exists in IsolatedStorageFile

```
IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
store.FileExists(dbName)  // returns true
```

i added this file to storage through this method:

```
Assembly assem = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
CopyFromContentToStorage(assem.FullName.Substring(0, assem.FullName.IndexOf(',')), dbName);

    private void CopyFromContentToStorage(String assemblyName, String dbName)
    {
        IsolatedStorageFile store =
            IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        System.IO.Stream src =
            Application.GetResourceStream(
                new Uri("/" + assemblyName + ";component/" + dbName,
                        UriKind.Relative)).Stream;
        IsolatedStorageFileStream dest =
            new IsolatedStorageFileStream(dbName,
                System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
                System.IO.FileAccess.Write, store);
        src.Position = 0;
        CopyStream(src, dest);
        dest.Flush();
        dest.Close();
        src.Close();
        dest.Dispose();
    }
```

i tested this app on two devices that running windows phone 8 * 8.1 . but it works correctly on those devices;

is this a bug in windows mobile 10 or i must change my code?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't write the file during first run, and then detected it was there? What happens if you do a "Rebuild" with Visual Studio (that should also clear the data folder)?

Comment: even after Rebuilding that apply Full Deployment (first uninstall - then install) problem exists. i have not any problem with windows phone 8 or 8.1 . but problem occurs in windows 10 build 10166 and 10512 @PeterTorr-MSFT

Comment: I can reproduce your problem - thanks for reporting. I am following up internally.

Comment: this problem also exists in latest windows 10 mobile preview version (OS version : 10.0.10536.1004) @PeterTorr-MSFT

Comment: Yes, the issue is known and a fix will be in a later release.

Comment: i also see another issues in this build . when i tap on navigation drawer it opens with lag (animation is laggy). this problem also exists when i hold on a button to see its Menu Items @PeterTorr-MSFT

Comment: Thanks for being an insider, but this is not a general support thread. Please create a new post if you have a programming question, or file general bugs and feedback through the feedback app. Thanks!